# Am I able to track the timeout transactions in C#/.NET on SQLServer or Oracle databases?

Tags: c#, .net, database, transactions, timeout

Is it able to capture the timeouted transactions on SQLServer or Oracle database by using C#/.NET? Currently I am working on a windows service which needs to monitor a specific data table in SQLServer or Oracle but I don't know how can I implement such kind of requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in sql server, there are some new things introduced since version 2005, DMV (these are managmenet views of sql server), you can query them and get the data, some of them are related to Transactions as well.

Visit this link or Google more about "SQL Server DMV".

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/04/29/SQL-Server-2005-Get-full-information-about-transaction-locks.aspx

Regards,

Mazhar Karimi

Comment: Another thing which i wanna say is: There are Transaction begin time, which if you calculate it with you current time like,

TransactinBeginTime - GetDate = Transaction Elapsed Time,

Which should be less than default transaction time out set.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And how about Oracle database?

Comment: Sorry, not sure about Oracle, will try to find something and let you know.